# INSERTAR HTML EN PHP EN WORDPRESS

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Resulta que tengo un wordpress y quiero modificar un php e insertar una llamada html de un plugin para cargar contenido en esa ubicación.

Pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo, he toqueteado pero no hay manera de que cargue correctamente el contenido.

Ese código que yo inserto es leido por el plugin widget shorcode, que a su vez carga contenido del plugin content blocks.

En ese content block tengo los codigos de adsense.

Pero nada no aparecen.

El codigo que tengo que insertar es: [widget id="custom_post_widget-8"]

Alguna idea?

Eternamente agradecido!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y porque querrias insertarlo en el medio de un php, cuando no tenes ni idea de como, y es muy peligroso. Simplemente insertalo en un widget html de wordpress y que lo muestre tu theme...

Comment: Hola! Procura no usar mayúscula sostenida en el sitio, que suele asimilarse a que gritas y pues veo que no es la idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Me cuesta bastante de entender tu pregunta pero creo haber entendido que lo que quieres es ejecutar un shortcode (no llamada html) que te proporciona el plugin.

Esto lo puedes poner directamente en cualquier bloque de texto de la página o en un widget pero si lo que quieres es modificar un php e incrustar la llamada por código, tendrás que localizar el fichero a modificar, editarlo y ejecutar la llamada mediante la instrucción do_shortcode(); de WordPress.

En este caso imagino que será:

```
 echo do_shortcode('[widget id="custom_post_widget-8"]');
```

Siempre englobado dentro de las etiquetas <?php correspondientes, evidentemente.

Espero que haya podido ayudar.